# Porque numpy.random() é mais lento que random()?

Tags: python, random, numpy

O objetivo do meu código é gerar um conjunto de números aleatórios uniformes, calcular a norma deles como se fossem componentes de um vetor e verificar se a norma está dentro de um certo intervalo:

Fiz duas funções diferentes que fazem a mesma coisa, cada uma usando uma biblioteca diferente:

```
def funcao_1(n):

    norma_random = 0
    for i in range(n):
        norma_random += ((random.uniform(-1,1)**2))**(1/2)
        
    if norma_random <= 1:
        return 1

    else:
        return 0

def funcao2(n):

    coordenadas = np.random.uniform(-1,1,n)
    norma_numpy = np.linalg.norm(coordenadas)

    if norma_numpy <= 1:
        return 1

    else:
        return 0
```

Na segunda parte do meu código uso uma das duas funções para fazer esse sorteio várias vezes:

```
N = 1000000
for n in range(1,11):
    k = 0
    V = 2**n

    for i in range(N):
        k += funcao1(n)

I = (k/N)*V
print('Volume {}-th dimensional: {}'.format(n, I))
```

Rodei essa segunda parte do código usando as duas funções func1() e func2()

Usando func1():

Tempo total rodando: 41.47705054283142 segundos

Usando func2():

Tempo total rodando: 113.81564688682556 segundos

Ou seja, usando a biblioteca numpy para gerar os números aleatórios o código demora mais.

Também fiz alguns testes usando %timeit. Comparei primeiros as funções inteiras:

```
%timeit funcao1(n)
1.26 µs ± 171 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit funcao2(n)
9.91 µs ± 664 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Depois comparei as partes equivalentes de cada função:

Primeiro comparar as operações de gerar os vetores aleatórios e calcular a norma:

```
%timeit "coordenadas = np.random.uniform(-1,1,n)" "norma_numpy = np.linalg.norm(coordenadas)"
14.4 ns ± 1.61 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000000 loops each)

%timeit "norma_random = 0" "for i in range(n): norma_random += (random.uniform(-1,1)**2)"
13.8 ns ± 0.752 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000000 loops each)
```

Depois a parte condicional do problema (onde a única diferença que consegui encontrar é que o numpy tem seu próprio data type inteiro):

```
%timeit "if norma_numpy<=1: True" "else: return 0"
13.6 ns ± 0.733 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000000 loops each)

%timeit "if norma_random<=1: True" "else: return 0"
13.3 ns ± 0.554 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000000 loops each)
```

Então, gostaria de saber se alguem tem alguma noção de onde surge essa diferença de eficiência  e o porquê não encontro diferença nenhuma quando testo as partes separadas do código.

Comment: de onde vem a variável "norma" no seu código? ela não está definida em nenhuma das suas duas funções.

Comment: Eu tava usando norma nas duas funções. Depois mudei o nome em cada função pra ficar mais fácil de entender. Vou editar o post

Answer (score 2):

O numpy.random vai ser mais rápido - mas pra vetores maiores. Você está usando  `n` de 1 a 10 - para valores tão pequenos, uma lista é criada muito mais rápido que um `numpy.array` - que tem que inicializar vários estados internos pra poder trabalhar com quantidades grandes de número.

Não se se faz sentido na conta que você quer fazer, mas experimente diminuir N e aumentar o n - com n na faixa de ~1000 acredito que a criação das estruturas do numpy já seja amortizada.